# DBT Post_hook update statement

Tags: dbt

I need to define an update statement in the post_hook. something like this:

```
post_hook = """ UPDATE {{ this }}
SET status = 0
WHERE date NOT IN (
SELECT MAX(date)
FROM {{ this }}
 )
AND id NOT IN (
Select id
from {{ ref('table2') }}
where date in (
SELECT MAX(date)
FROM {{ this }})
               ); """
```

The problem is that in post_hook the update statments cannot have nested select statments. Does anyone have any idead how I can workarround this?

```
post_hook = """ UPDATE {{ this }}
SET status = 0
WHERE date NOT IN (
SELECT MAX(date)
FROM {{ this }}
 )
AND id NOT IN (
Select id
from {{ ref('table2') }}
where date in (
SELECT MAX(date)
FROM {{ this }})
               ); """
```